# re-use a guard in Scala

Tags: scala

I often find myself wanting to reuse the result of a guard evaluation in scala, e.g.

```
blah match {
  case Blah(a, b) if expensive(a) < 10 =>
     expensive(a)
  case _ => b
}
```

Is this possible using some lesser-known incantation? (putting an `@` on the `expensive` doesn't work)

Will this be possible anytime soon?

Comment: +1 because this is an interesting appearance of a quite common problem (It's quite common to have things like `if(res=expensive){ /*something with res*/}` in more imperative languages.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do something similar using a custom extractor. This should work:

```
case class Blah(a: Int, b: Int)

object expensive {
  def unapply(x: Int): Option[Double] = Some(math.cos(x))
}

Blah(1, 1) match {
  case Blah(a @ expensive(e), b) if e < 10 => println(a, b, e)
  case _ => println("nothing")
}
```

Be sure that the `expensive` is really more expensive that creating an `Option` object, which is what the above does.

Comment: the confusing thing is that the `a` and `e` are "the wrong way round" from the intuitive syntax. It is best not to define the `a` at all in order to keep it clearer. (i.e. `a` is the original value, `e` is the result of doing the expensive calculation)